# Returning if the user hits the x in the top corner of a JOptionPane.showMessageDialog

Tags: java, joptionpane

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, roll, "Dice Game", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, die);
```

When I run this, I want to know if the user hits x so I can change a boolean, roll is a JTextArea, die is an image icon, null is my layout.

The problem is the showMessageDialog is a void method. So I can't check. Thanks.

I do not have a JFrame nor do I want one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ShowMessageDialog` is not designed for this. It is used to display a message, not to get user feedback. You should use a showConfirmDialog for your purpose, with `OK_CANCEL_OPTION` because it is really what you want: clicking on the X button is like using a Cancel button.

If you really do not want a Cancel button, then <s>you have to create your own JDialog</s> actually you can use JOptionPane.showOptionDialog:

```
int result = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, roll, "Dice Game", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, die, new Object[] { "OK"}, null);
```

`result` will be 0 if the user press OK, and -1 if the user close the dialog with the X button.

Comment: Thanks this worked! Is there a way to use JOptionPane to make an input that can have an image icon? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

A message dialog is for presenting a message to a user, so there shouldn't be a semantic difference between dismissing it using "OK" or dismissing it using the "X".

If you're looking for input, perhaps a confirmation dialog is what you want, which returns an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Why You need that? Message dialog is an information dialog and there isn't need to detect which button was pressed (OK or X).